# Newey-West vs Cochrane-Orcutt

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I have time series of 189 observations and I want to regress $y$ on $x$. My modeling procedure is the following:

1. I run an  OLS and I  get the constant significant and b not significant (but I know that the S.E. are incorrect, so I need to correct them).
2. I test for serial correlation using the Breusch-Godfrey LM test and Durbin's alternative test and both reject the null of no serial correlation.
3. I adjust the S.E. using Newey-West and again I get similar results for S.E. and I still have the constant significant and the b not significant.
4. I run the Cochrane-Orcutt and I get constant not significant and the b significant.

How should I choose between Newey-West and Cochrane-Orcutt?